# Grep to match all lines of patternfile (perl -e ok too)

Tags: perl, command-line, grep

I'm looking for a simple/elegant way to grep a file such that every returned line must match every line of a pattern file.

With input file

```
acb
bc
ca
bac
```

And pattern file

```
a
b
c
```

The command should return

```
acb
bac
```

I tried to do this with `grep -f` but that returns if it matches a single pattern in the file (and not all). I also tried something with a recursive call to `perl -ne` (foreach line of the pattern file, call perl -ne on the search file and try to grep in place)  but I couldn't get the syntax parser to accept a call to perl from perl, so not sure if that's possible.

I thought there's probably a more elegant way to do this, so I thought I'd check. Thanks!

===UPDATE===

Thanks for your answers so far, sorry if I wasn't clear but I was hoping for just a one-line result (creating a script for this seems too heavy, just wanted something quick). I've been thinking about it some more and I came up with this so far:

```
perl -n -e 'chomp($_); print " | grep $_  "' pattern | xargs echo "cat input"
```

which prints

```
cat input | grep a | grep b | grep c
```

This string is what I want to execute, I just need to somehow execute it now. I tried an additional pipe to eval

```
perl -n -e 'chomp($_); print " | grep $_  "' pattern | xargs echo "cat input" | eval
```

Though that gives the message:

```
xargs: echo: terminated by signal 13
```

I'm not sure what that means?

Comment: Signal 13 is `SIGPIPE`.  The pipe was closed while `xargs` was writing to it; somewhat predictably, because there is nothing in `eval` which would ever read it.  Not at all clear what you are hoping to accomplish with the stuff from the `xargs` onward, anyhow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way using `perl`:

Content of `input`:

```
acb
bc
ca
bac
```

Content of `pattern`:

```
a
b
c
```

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

## Check arguments.
die qq[Usage: perl $0 <input-file> <pattern-file>\n] unless @ARGV == 2;

## Open files.
open my $pattern_fh, qq[<], pop @ARGV or die qq[ERROR: Cannot open pattern file: $!\n];
open my $input_fh, qq[<], pop @ARGV or die qq[ERROR: Cannot open input file: $!\n];

## Variable to save the regular expression.
my $str;

## Read patterns to match, and create a regex, with each string in a positive
## look-ahead.
while ( <$pattern_fh> ) { 
    chomp;
    $str .= qq[(?=.*$_)];
}

my $regex = qr/$str/;

## Read each line of data and test if the regex matches.
while ( <$input_fh> ) { 
    chomp;
    printf qq[%s\n], $_ if m/$regex/o;
}
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl input pattern
```

With following output:

```
acb
bac
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Perl, I suggest you read all the patterns into an array and compile them. Then you can read through your input file using `grep` to make sure all of the regexes match.

The code looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $ptn, '<', 'pattern.txt' or die $!;
my @patterns = map { chomp(my $re = $_); qr/$re/; } grep /\S/, <$ptn>;

open my $in, '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;
while (my $line = <$in>) {
  print $line unless grep { $line !~ $_ } @patterns;
}
```

**output**

```
acb
bac
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to read all the input lines and then start filtering by each pattern:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $in, '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;
my @matches = <$in>;
close $in;

open my $ptn, '<', 'pattern.txt' or die $!;
for my $pattern (<$ptn>) {
  chomp($pattern);
  @matches = grep(/$pattern/, @matches);
}
close $ptn;

print @matches;
```

**output**

```
acb
bac
```

Answer (score 0):

Not grep and not a one liner...

```
MFILE=file.txt
PFILE=patterns
i=0
while read line; do
  let i++
  pattern=$(head -$i $PFILE | tail -1)
  if [[ $line =~ $pattern  ]]; then
    echo $line
  fi
  # (or use sed instead of bash regex:
  # echo $line | sed -n "/$pattern/p"
done < $MFILE
```

Comment: It would be more efficient to have an inner loop over the lines in the pattern file than to reread it from the start on every iteration.  Furthermore, this will print the input line multiple times while looping over the patterns.

Answer (score 0):

A `bash`(Linux) based solution

```
#!/bin/sh
INPUTFILE=input.txt #Your input file
PATTERNFILE=patterns.txt # file with patterns
# replace new line with '|' using awk
PATTERN=`awk 'NR==1{x=$0;next}NF{x=x"|"$0}END{print x}' "$PATTERNFILE"`
PATTERNCOUNT=`wc -l <"$PATTERNFILE"`
# build regex of style :(a|b|c){3,}
PATTERN="($PATTERN){$PATTERNCOUNT,}"

egrep "${PATTERN}" "${INPUTFILE}"
```

Comment: This wrongly identifies "a a a" as a match when you wanted "c b a" or "a b c".  The length alone is not enough to properly solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a grep-only solution:

```
#!/bin/sh
foo ()
{
        FIRST=1
        cat pattern.txt | while read line; do
        if [ $FIRST -eq 1 ]; then
                FIRST=0
                echo -n "grep \"$line\""
        else
                echo -n "$STRING | grep \"$line\""
            fi
        done
}
STRING=`foo`
eval "cat input.txt | $STRING"
```